# Approach to evolve data schemas with Migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I come from a NodeJS background, where most of the frameworks don't include migrations support. I have a few doubts that I hope you'll be able to clarify:

Supose I defined a data schema for a product with a `name` and a `price`:

- If I create a migration and add a **required** column called `description` and run `db:migrate`, future products will require a description but what about the older ones?
- They will not be valid, or contain an empty description?
- Do I have to manually add descriptions to them?
- What if I set an optional value for the description? Will that be applied to older instances?
- If I reset all the migrations and run them again, will I lose any data?

What is the correct approach to handle this kind of situations where you evolve your schema, possibly rendering invalid older instances?

Answer (score 0):

regarding your questions:

- If I create a migration and add a required column called description
  and run db:migrate, future products will require a description but
  what about the older ones?

It depends on what happens in your migration. If you have a required value, you should ensure that old models are migrated as such that they will be valid afterwards too. If not you will run in problems then trying to update old entries because your model validation will deny update attempts (if your update will not include the newly required field)

- They will not be valid, or contain an empty description?

As mentioned it depends. If you migrate as such there will be some kind of default value for your new column, you are fine. Otherwise the old entries will just be set to NULL.

- Do I have to manually add descriptions to them?

If there is no way to somehow autogenerate your value or default value can't be applied, yes.

- What if I set an optional value for the description? Will that be applied to older instances?

If not explicitly defined in your migration your old entries will be set to NULL for the new column.

- If I reset all the migrations and run them again, will I lose any data?

Most likely, migrations can be build in the UP and DOWN way but downways you are loosing information which might not be restoreable based on the information loss. So removing all migrations is like dropping the whole database.

But why would someone want to reset all migrations at once? As your database is evolving you should treat it like a growing child, you won't get back the years spent on their education but you can teach them to behave better thus forgetting unnecessary information (dropping unneeded columns with a further UP migration).

> What is the correct approach to handle this kind of situations where
>   you evolve your schema, possibly rendering invalid older instances?

You might blame me but it ... depends ;)

If following update attempts ensure to render the model to be valid, you simply don't have to care. If not, you have to care either within the migration or some kind of scripty or handy attempt to render them back valid again.